# Careful selection text in OnTouchEvent

Tags: android, touch-event, textselection

I wrote a code for select a part of text but But I can't find the exact point of beginning and ending.

My code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();

        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            lastX = (int) event.getX();
            lastY = (int) event.getY();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
                int currentX = (int) event.getX();
                int currentY = (int) event.getY();
                int xDistance = Math.abs(currentX - lastX);
                int yDistance = Math.abs(currentY - lastY);

            final Spannable WordtoSpan = (Spannable) mText;

                int line = mLayout.getLineForVertical(yDistance);
                int offset = mLayout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, xDistance);
                WordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), line,
offset, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                txtContent.setText(WordtoSpan);

                break;
        }
        }
    }
```

Please help me, I really need it.

Comment: what are you asking....?

Comment: My Question is clear. I wanna select a part of text but I can't.
Could you tell me what I should do?